# Strange svg path cropping after applying mask

Tags: svg, crop, mask

[image: cropped paths]

I have four paths (simplified to straight lines) with stroke=34 for two of which (2, 4) the empty mask (100%x100% filled with white) is applied.  Such thing happens with all kind of paths which cropped vertically and horizontally after mask applying.

Can anybody tell me what's going on here and how this cropping can be avoided?

[Source SVG file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14328131/test1.svg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the default for the [`maskUnits`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#MaskElementMaskUnitsAttribute) attribute. If you don't specify `maskUnits` then it defaults to `objectBoundingBox`, and the x, y, width and height of the <mask> is `-10%, -10%, 120%, 120%` respectively (if not explicitly set to anything else). This together results in the clipping region that you see.

It seems that you want `maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` judging from the example source. However, note that you may wish to use a <clipPath> instead of a <mask> unless you need to do a gradient fade or otherwise advanced clipping shape. Using <clipPath> (and the corresponding property `clip-path`) is typically better from a performance standpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the maskUnits!  
I can't use clipPath because of I need to "erase" some area from the shapes to which the mask is applied which I do with black paths on white background.

Comment: BTW you can also make holes with clip paths. Although I admit it is generally eaier to do with masks.

Comment: Saved my evening :-D Thank you @extempl and @Erik. `xxxUnits` seems to be more thorough than I thought first.